# Program UICollectionViewCell Programmatically

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to create a cell programmatically without using the story board, but I stumble upon some problems. The cell code is as following.

```
import UIKit

class ProductCategoryCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {


required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    self.setupCell()
}


var productCategoryImageView :UIImageView!

func setupCell(){
    //seting up the imageView as subView
    productCategoryImageView = UIImageView()
    productCategoryImageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    let subViewDictionary = ["productCategoryImageViewKey" : productCategoryImageView]


    let productCategoryImageViewWidth = contentView.bounds.size.width
    let productCategoryImageViewHeight = contentView.bounds.size.height
    let productCategoryImageViewHorizontalConstrain = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:[productCategoryImageViewKey(\(productCategoryImageViewWidth))]", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(rawValue: 0), metrics: nil, views: subViewDictionary)
    let productCategoryImageViewVerticalConstrain = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:[productCategoryImageViewKey(\(productCategoryImageViewHeight))]", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(rawValue: 0), metrics: nil, views: subViewDictionary)

    productCategoryImageView.addConstraints(productCategoryImageViewHorizontalConstrain)


    productCategoryImageView.addConstraints(productCategoryImageViewVerticalConstrain)



    contentView.addSubview(productCategoryImageView)
    contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 1, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 0.4)
}
```

}

I am trying to create a subImageView which will be size of the cell, however, it doesn't scale to to the size of the cell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The size of the cell is not known when the init method is called. So setting the width and height to `contentView.bounds.size.width` and `contentView.bounds.size.height` won't work.

Instead of adding constraints for horizontal and vertical sizes you can add left, right, top and bottom constraints, like this:

```
let productCategoryImageViewHorizontalConstrain = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:|-0-[productCategoryImageViewKey]-0-|", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(rawValue: 0), metrics: nil, views: subViewDictionary)
let productCategoryImageViewVerticalConstrain = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:|-0-[productCategoryImageViewKey]-0-|", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(rawValue: 0), metrics: nil, views: subViewDictionary)
```

And you should also call `contentView.addSubview(productCategoryImageView)`
 before adding the constraints.

Comment: Thanks... Why didn't i think of it. Thanks so much

Answer (score -1):

/* create a UICollectionView Cell in Programmatically as above Code */

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    self.view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];

    UICollectionViewFlowLayout *layout=[[UICollectionViewFlowLayout alloc] init];
    uicollection=[[UICollectionView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame collectionViewLayout:layout];
    [uicollection setDataSource:self];
    [uicollection setDelegate:self];

    [uicollection registerClass:[UICollectionViewCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cellIdentifier"];
    [uicollection setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];

    [self.view addSubview:uicollection];


    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 15;
}

// The cell that is returned must be retrieved from a call to -dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:forIndexPath:
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UICollectionViewCell *cell=[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cellIdentifier" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.backgroundColor=[UIColor greenColor];

    return cell;
}

- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return CGSizeMake(50, 50);
}


- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

Comment: I don understand what you are trying to do .. I have a UIcollectionViewControl already and i have called the itemforSize delegate methods to scale it to a specific size. However, it is the subImage in the Cell that doesn't scale to the size of the cell.

Comment: The question is tagged "Swift", not "Objective-C".